# HTML: How to adapt video to iFrame size?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, iframe, bootstrap-4

When I load the video from youtube, I get this result:
[image]
When I load the video from [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/), I get this result:
[image]
**PROBLEM:** Even though, it's the **exact same video**, when I load it from Cloudinary, it doesn't **fill** all of the `iframe` window.
This is the code responsible for both implementation:

```
<iframe
className="embed-responsive-item"
src={
  generic_profile.videoURL == undefined
    ? "https://www.youtube.com/embed/wYxDJOFgDw0"
    : cloudinayURL
}
frameborder="0"
allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
allowfullscreen
></iframe>
```

**NOTE:** I am using **ReactJs**.
**QUESTION:** Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I just used the video tag and it solved the problem:

```
 <video controls="true" class="embed-responsive-item">
                <source
                  src={
                    generic_profile.videoURL == undefined
                      ? "https://www.youtube.com/embed/wYxDJOFgDw0"
                      : generic_profile.videoURL
                  }
                  type="video/mp4"
            /> <!---now it will work well--->
          </video>
```